# Why does Selenium return the result which is not my respect randomly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, random

Python Selenium the website is [http://xkz.cbirc.gov.cn/jr/，reflush](http://xkz.cbirc.gov.cn/jr/%EF%BC%8Creflush) it and you will find the confirm messageBox

```py
driver.get("http://xkz.cbirc.gov.cn/jr/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

table_yanZhengMa = wait.until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[5]/table"))

visibilityMy = driver.find_element_by_id("show_msg").get_attribute('style')

print(visibilityMy)

if (visibilityMy.find("visibility: visible") >= 0):

    print("需要输入验证码")
else:

    tmpPrice = wait.until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
            (
                By.XPATH,
                "/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/a"#"//div[@class='sku-name']",  价格
            )
        )
    )

    print(tmpPrice[0].text)

    print(driver.find_element_by_id("queryResult").text)
```

[image]

Comment: It seems your code only wants the style of the element. .get_attribute('style')

Comment: What did you actually want.

Comment: for example，the browser  ejects  6 windows of Verification code， my program can find 5 windows of Verification code. the remain one can not be find. i dont know why ,and how to fix it.  the html file contains   <div  id="show_msg"   style="z-index: 20001; width: 450px; display: block; visibility: visible;"> ,   but my program output only  "z-index: 20001; width: 450px;"  with style, this cause my program can not find the Verification code window. how to fix it?

Comment: maybe you can visit  http://xkz.cbirc.gov.cn/jr/ ,and refrush it until eject Verification code window,then you can use my code to find this Verification code window. can you find this window every time?or can not find it rendomly?

Comment: You can refresh the page like so to find it. It takes a little while till it finds the proper one.

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh the page to do so.

```
driver.get("http://xkz.cbirc.gov.cn/jr/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

while True:
    table_yanZhengMa = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[5]/table")))
    print(table_yanZhengMa)
    visibilityMy = driver.find_element_by_id("show_msg").get_attribute('style')  
    print(visibilityMy)
    if(visibilityMy.find("visibility: visible")>=0):
        print("需要输入验证码")
        break
    driver.refresh()
```

Comment: thanks！but my logic is when visibilityMy.find("visibility: visible")<0, i must output the DOM's text, I change my code in the first floor.if when   visibilityMy.find("visibility: visible")<0, you refresh , the logic may be confused

Comment: This refreshes when visibility <0.

Comment: If it finds it leaves the loop. It might actually pop up again.

Comment: but my logic is when visibilityMy.find("visibility: visible")<0, i must output the DOM's text. How to realize it?thanks

Comment: thanks! but i think refreshing is not good idea.if  Put it outside the loop, and visibilityMy.find("visibility: visible")>=0, you will input code continuously ，that's Crazy. I want to know ,why my program can not find this Verification code window through visibilityMy.find("visibility: visible")>=0? can I send my program to you to run?

Comment: The page doesn't have it always.

Comment: It's probably detecting a bot.

Comment: "The page doesn't have it always. "——maybe the server know your ip which is outside of China.But in China ,I get it.

Comment: Who can help me ?Can you reproduce this problem？my python program get style=  "z-index: 20001; width: 450px;"  while in browser  this is          style="z-index: 20001; width: 450px; display: block; visibility: visible;"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved。It is because I use Firefox browser. if I use chrome, This problem no longer arises。 But why firefox  leads to this problem， I do Not know！ Anybody know？